# Right control key being mapped to forward slash (/)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

In a certain PC (Windows 7), the right control key is being mapped to "/". In other words, every time I press the right control key, / appears on the screen.

Things that I've already tried:

- Uninstalling the driver
- Changing keyboard

Since I changed the keyboard and the problem continued, it must be a software problem, but I still don't know the cause. Any ideas?

Comment: If you think it's software, try a different OS (IE: Linux LiveCD).  Try Windows in Safe Mode.  Try logging into Windows as a different user. Ensure that Windows is set to use the right kind of keyboard.  Ensure Windows is using the expect Language.

Comment: Why's this being downvoted? There's nothing wrong with it as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: after downloading and installing [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/), I opened it and saw that there was a weird mapping for the right control key.

The fix was to select the mapping and delete it with SharpKeys. After that, the key started working normally.

Comment: CodePlex is about to die in a few days. SharpKeys moved to GitHub: https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys